# Reading email field from a certificate signing request (CSR) with C#

Tags: c#, x509certificate, csr

I'm using the following code to read the attributes of a CSR:

```
string csr = myCSR;
CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 request = new CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10();
request.InitializeDecode(csr, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64_ANY);
request.CheckSignature();
string tmp = ReadDnsSan(request);
string attribs = (((CX500DistinguishedName)request.Subject).Name);
```

in attribs I get common name, organization, department, city, country, but not the email address

Shouldn't be mandatory for a CSR?
Is there a way to read it with C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in attribs I get common name, organization, department

you are going in the right direction, but it appears that email RDN attribute is not presented in the subject field.

> Shouldn't be mandatory for a CSR?

no. Moreover, entire Subject field is optional. Therefore, you may need to modify your code accordingly. There might be a situation when Subject field is empty, then subject information shall be presented in the Subject Alternative Names extension.

Therefore, if `E=` or `Email=` attributes are missing from the subject string, then this attribute is not presented there.